# mysql layer as interpreter for PostgreSQL database

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, jdbc

I bought a web application some years ago with a mysql backend (few tables and relationships) using JDBC for the connection. My company now decided to migrate all the databases to PostgreSQL. We contacted the company sold us the application but it seems they don't want to do the migration. So my question is the following: Is there a way to put a layer between the application and the database to convert the calls coming from the application? Some sort of java library doing the role of interpreter, that convert mysql requests in postgree responses and viceversa.

Comment: JDBC *is* that layer.

Comment: @philipxy Only kind-of. If you send `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to PostgreSQL you'll get a `SYNTAX ERROR`. Lots of other such cases too. I'm guessing the app uses some, or lots, of non-ANSI-standard syntax and functionality. Lets face it, nearly everything does. And it gets more exciting if you're dealing with an app that uses legacy MySQL  stuff like backtick quoting, quotes literals with double quotes not single quotes, uses backslashes for escaping instead of doubling quotes, etc etc.

Comment: @CraigRinger That is not an example of using JDBC. That is an example of not using JDBC. Or have I got the wrong API in mind?

Comment: @philipxy You do. I think you are thinking of ORMs and query generators. JPA, Hibernate, MyBatis, and so on.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but I don't think that magic/nirvana/heaven layer exists. JDBC can/will pass SQL that a backend might not recognize, it doesn't convert `date_diff(dt1,dt2)` to `dt1-dt2` or `ifnull()` to `coalesce()` or recognize that @variables were used as a substitute for `row_number()` ... and much much more

Comment: Ok I am a bit confused. When I run the app I have to configure the server, database port and nothing else,, so I immagine the mysql jar (in the lib) file is the one receiving the call from the app and converting them in real mysql queries. Now I imagine if I am able to intercept these calls (for example a specific server:database combination in the configuration )with a simple java program using jdbc connected with a postgreSql jar file I can map such calls (if different) from one to another sql database.